# I dont understand why my first Elixir script failing

Tags: elixir

I am trying to learn Elixir.

I found this demo syntax:

```
#---
# http://media.pragprog.com/titles/elixir16/code/spawn/pmap1.exs
# Excerpted from "Programming Elixir
# published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
# Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material,
# courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
# We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose.
# Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/elixir16 for more book information.
#---
defmodule Parallel do
  def pmap(collection, func) do
    collection
    |> Enum.map(&(Task.async(fn -> func.(&1) end)))
    |> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)
  end
end

result = Parallel.pmap 1..1000, &(&1 ​*​ &1)
```

I put the above syntax in a file: pmap1.exs

Next I tried to run it with a simple shell command:

```
dan@h78:~/elxr/public/notes $ elixir pmap1.exs
** (SyntaxError) pmap1.exs:18: unexpected token: "​" (column 38, codepoint U+200B)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
dan@h78:~/elxr/public/notes $
```

Am I running it incorrectly?

Do I have a syntax error somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, in your code sample there are two "zero width spaces" (Unicode codepoint 200B), one on each side of the `*` character.  After removing the two zero width spaces, your code runs fine for me.

(You are assigning a value to `result`, but not printing it or doing something else with it, so it says `warning: variable "result" is unused`, but that's the next step.  `IO.inspect(result)` is a quick way of doing that.)